# now.js hosted node app crashes after a while

Tags: node.js, discord, vercel

I'm making bots for discord using discord.js library and I'm hosting them on now.js.
However I've had some annoying issues with now.js hosting.

When I try to host the app using now.js alone it crashed before the build is finished after 5mn and prints

```
No open port found. Make sure 'npm start' creates an HTTP server on a port (any).
```

So I add http server using npm and create a localhost server on build and I launch my bot at the same time using this npm start command

```
http-server -p 8000 & node index
```

When I do that the build works fine, I then scale it to 1 instance that never sleeps and I have no issue. However after a few days the app crashes and prints that

```
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
Killed
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! errno 137
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! Selfbot@0.1.0 now-start: `http-server -p 8000 & node index`
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! Exit status 137
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! 
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! Failed at the Selfbot@0.1.0 now-start script.
09/05 08:44 PM (5d)
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

From this error I understand that the issue is with the http server getting stopped. And this is a problem because that means I need to restart the app every few days. How can I prevent that?

Comment: It's likely to do with the `http-server` not getting any traffic. https://zeit.co/docs/deployment-types/node#deployment-inactivity

Comment: How can I prevent that? Cause discord commands are not considered "traffic".

Comment: Try contacting their support. Other than that you can expose the server and send fake traffic to it from somewhere else, or just host it somewhere else like aws or digitalocean.